# error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path' or its corresponding type declarations. when trying to migrate in heroku app with Knex

Tags: typescript, heroku, database-migration, knex.js, dirname

I want to migrate a SQlite database:

```
knex --knexfile knexfile.ts migrate:latest
```

However this gives the following typescript error:

```
⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
knexfile.ts:1:18 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import path from 'path';
                   ~~~~~~
knexfile.ts:4:1 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'module'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node`.

4 module.exports = {
  ~~~~~~
knexfile.ts:7:28 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.

7     filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'database.sqlite'),
                             ~~~~~~~~~
knexfile.ts:10:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.

10     directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'migrations'),
                               ~~~~~~~~~
knexfile.ts:13:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.

13     directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'seeds'),
                               ~~~~~~~~~

TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
knexfile.ts:1:18 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import path from 'path';
                   ~~~~~~
knexfile.ts:4:1 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'module'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node`.

4 module.exports = {
  ~~~~~~
knexfile.ts:7:28 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.

7     filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'database.sqlite'),
                             ~~~~~~~~~
knexfile.ts:10:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.

10     directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'migrations'),
                               ~~~~~~~~~
knexfile.ts:13:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.

13     directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'seeds'),
                               ~~~~~~~~~
```

Bellow is my `knexfile`:

```
import path from 'path';
import 'dotenv/config';

module.exports = {
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: {
    filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'database.sqlite'),
  },
  migrations: {
    directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'migrations'),
  },
  seeds: {
    directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'seeds'),
  },
  useNullAsDefault: true,
};
```

How can I address such issue?
I am using the following dependencies:

| devDependencies | dependencies |
| --- | --- |
| "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2", | "@vscode/sqlite3": "^5.0.8" |
| "@types/cors": "^2.8.7", | "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3" |
| "@types/express": "^4.17.7", | "cors": "^2.8.5" |
| "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.8" | "dotenv": "^8.2.0" |
| "@types/node": "^17.0.24" | "express": "^4.17.1" |
| "knex-types": "^0.3.2" | "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1" |
| "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.56" | "knex": "^1.0.7" |
| "typescript": "^4.6.3" | "ts-node": "^8.10.2" |
|  | "sqlite3": "^5.0.3" |

## Edit `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "imonitor-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/server.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build/src/server.js",
    "postinstall": "tsc",
    "dev": "tsnd --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules --respawn src/server.ts",
    "knex:migrate": "knex --knexfile knexfile.ts migrate:latest",
    "knex:seed": "knex --knexfile knexfile.ts seed:run",
    "knex:rollback": "knex --knexfile knexfile.ts migrate:rollback",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/lucasbbs/imonitor-backend.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.14.0",
    "npm": "8.3.1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/lucasbbs/imonitor-backend/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/lucasbbs/imonitor-backend#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.7",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.8",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.24",
    "knex-types": "^0.3.2",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.56",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vscode/sqlite3": "^5.0.8",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "knex": "^1.0.7",
    "pg": "^8.3.0",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TypeScript

The immediate issue here is that you're trying use TypeScript at runtime, but you've defined `@types/node` as a development dependency. By default, [Heroku strips `devDependencies` from your project after building it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation).

One option is to [skip the pruning step](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#skip-pruning), which will leave your `devDependencies` in place, but that likely isn't the right choice. Normally you'll want these dependencies to be stripped. Among other reasons, this reduces the size of your application slug.

Another option is to move `@types/node` from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`. But I don't think that's the right move here, either. My gut says you shouldn't be using TypeScript at all in production.

Since your `build` script simply runs `tsc`, I wonder if it has already compiled your `knexfile.ts` to `knexfile.js`. If it did, you can try running the JavaScript file directly:

```
knex --knexfile knexfile.js migrate:latest
```

Since that's the default file that Knex looks for, you can actually skip the argument entirely:

```
knex migrate:latest
```

### SQLite

This should get your migrations going, but you're going to run into another issue: Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) makes SQLite a poor database choice.

Any changes you make to the database, including schema changes introduced by your migrations, will be lost whenever your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

To resolve that issue, you'll want to switch from SQLite to a client-server database. Heroku's own [Postgres service](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) is a reasonable starting point, but there are [other database addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores) if you prefer. You can also host your own database elsewhere on the cloud, e.g. on Microsoft Azure or AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with another module, I was trying to import @mui/x-data-grid in a file, but got the same error. I found as mentioned by @Chris above that the library was in the dependencies object not in the devDependencies, so I just have to remove it and install it again on the devDependencies, now the error message is gone. It seems that @types/node must be in the same dependencies object (dev or not) as the module you are trying to use.